# Count number of clients that have seen everyone

Tags: powerbi, dax

Dummy Data example :[Dummy Data (the way I can see it in a PowerBIMatrix)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyCta.png)

Imagine you are a doctor and you want to make sure your patients are seeing everyone one of your nurses. That is what % I am looking for.

I need a powerbi Dax and nothing on the internet is helping me. I have a table it has Staff Names, Client Names and interactions. I need to see the number of clients who have an interaction >0  with all staff members. So if one nurse gets missed, that client wouldn’t be in the count.

Both the staff name and the client name can appear multiple times in one given date range, but I just care if they seen them at least one time in that period I will count them. I have it set up as a matrix so I can visually see it, but I need to find a percent automatically.

There are two slicers of service date and staff name in my report. As the dates and staff names change and I need my dax to be dependent on the those changes. Because sometimes I have two staff selected others I have 5 etc. please I have tried so many formulas and nothing is working. Every dax I try either adds up all the interactions or it says 0 staff seen all the clients when I am looking at it and I know they did.eventually I need a percentage.

I have attached sample dummy data of what my table looks like

The raw data looks like:

It goes: Client Name, Staff Name, Date

|Jones |Stanley|10/20/2021|

|Jones |Danny|10/21/2021|

|Jones |Elle |10/21/2021|

|Smith |Stanley |10/18/2021|

|Smith |Danny|10/19/2021|

|Smith |Elle |10/23/2021|

|Murray |Elle|10/21/2021|

|Murray |Stanley|10/21/2021|

|Murray |Elle|10/21/2021|

So here you can see that Murray did not see all three staff members therefore the % should be 66% of clients saw all three staff

Any help is greatly appreciated

Many many formulas most are returning blank even though I see people with that had appts with all the staff. Or it’s just adding all the clients

Comment: The sample data didn't come through

Answer (score 0):

Not totally sure this is the best way to do it, but you can't do a multi-column join in DAX like you can in (say) T-SQL, so I had to cheat a lot. I created a calculated column in the Meetings table:

```
StaffClient = [Staff Name] & "|" & [Client Name]
```

and then I created this table to generate all possible combinations of StaffName and ClientName:

```
Staff x Client = 
ADDCOLUMNS(
    CROSSJOIN (
    SELECTCOLUMNS(DimStaff,"Staff Name",[Staff Name]),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(DimClient,"Client Name",[Client Name])
    ),
    "StaffClient", [Staff Name] & "|" & [Client Name]
)
```

Now I can subtract to get the missing (All combinations minus meetings):

```
Missing Meetings = EXCEPT(
                       SELECTCOLUMNS('Staff x Client',"StaffClient",[Staff Name] & "|" & [Client Name]),
                       SELECTCOLUMNS('Meetings',"StaffClient",[Staff Name] & "|" & [Client Name])
)
```

and then I re-split the "StaffClient" column into two.

```
Client = RIGHT('Missing Meetings'[StaffClient],FIND("|",'Missing Meetings'[StaffClient],1))

Staff = LEFT('Missing Meetings'[StaffClient],FIND("|",'Missing Meetings'[StaffClient],1)-1)
```

Comment: I can edit my sql query, but unsure how to do that. Is it a self join those joins trip me up. I could most definitely do this in SQL (I use SSMS)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you don't have the staff in one table and the clients in another, it becomes more difficult, but not a lot. I created the Staff and Client tables from the data (just inserted the unique values from each). Then this was super easy. Just cross join the Staff and Client tables and then subtract the meetings, like this:

```
use tempdb;
go

CREATE TABLE Meeting(ClientName VARCHAR(10),StaffName VARCHAR(10), MtgDate DATE);
GO
INSERT INTO Meeting VALUES
('Jones' ,'Stanley','10/20/2021')
,('Jones' ,'Danny','10/21/2021')
,('Jones' ,'Elle' ,'10/21/2021')
,('Smith' ,'Stanley' ,'10/18/2021')
,('Smith' ,'Danny','10/19/2021')
,('Smith' ,'Elle' ,'10/23/2021')
,('Murray' ,'Elle','10/21/2021')
,('Murray' ,'Stanley','10/21/2021')
,('Murray' ,'Elle','10/21/2021');

CREATE TABLE Staff(StaffName VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE Client(ClientName VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO Staff(StaffName)
SELECT DISTINCT StaffName
FROM Meeting;

INSERT INTO Client(ClientName)
SELECT DISTINCT ClientName
FROM Meeting;

/* now that I have Client and Staff as separate tables,
   this is much neater */


SELECT sc.StaffName, sc.ClientName
FROM
    (SELECT StaffName, ClientName 
    FROM Staff 
    CROSS JOIN Client) sc
EXCEPT 
    (SELECT StaffName, ClientName
    FROM Meeting)
ORDER BY sc.StaffName, sc.ClientName;
```

Comment: Staff is in a different table. I use clients for names and Id, staff has staff  name and then an appt table which lists the staff name they seen and client id and appt date… I cannot create another table as I am direct query off my database. So can’t use cte either